# Python's json.dumps function failing to indent

Tags: python, json, pymongo, bson, amadeus

I then have a function, loadDatabase, which fully updates a database and then returns it as a JSON (to later be printed to the screen)

The problem is that it prints it in a format that isn't very readable, which normally would be an easy fix with the json.dumps() or bson.json_util.dumps() functions, which can accept an indent parameter. However, I've tried both and neither seem to have any effect.

My relevant code, I've commented out the lines I believe aren't important for this:

```
def loadDatabase():
    try:
        client.admin.command('ping')
        #logger.info("Successfully connected to MongoDB")
        #print("Database - You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
        #flightCollection.delete_many({}) 
        #flightCollection.insert_many(loadFlights())
        data = flightCollection.find({})
        output = json.dumps(str(data), indent=4)
        return output
    except Exception as e:
        #print(e)
        #logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        #logger.error(e)
        #logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        return "DATABASE ERROR: <br>"+str(e)

def loadFlights(): 
    response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers_search.get(
        originLocationCode='MAD',
        destinationLocationCode='ATH',
        departureDate=str(date.today()),
        adults=1)
    return response.data
```

What can I do to fix this? I've tried both dump functions, but beyond manually writing a function to parse it (which is doable but I don't think I should reinvent the wheel) I don't know what to do

I expected the output to be a formatted JSON, but instead it's all clumped together, eg.:

`"{'_id': ObjectId('6481bb02cbb598c58691b45e'), 'type': 'flight-offer', 'id': '2', 'source': 'GDS', 'instantTicketingRequired': False, 'nonHomogeneous': False, 'oneWay': False, 'lastTicketingDate': '2023-06-08', 'lastTicketingDateTime': '2023-06-08', 'numberOfBookableSeats': 3, 'itineraries': [{'duration': 'PT12H5M', 'segments': [{'departure': {'iataCode': 'MAD', 'terminal': '4S', 'at': '2023-06-08T22:10:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'TLV', 'terminal': '3', 'at': '2023-06-09T03:45:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'IZ', 'number': '232', 'aircraft': {'code': '73H'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'QS'}, 'duration': 'PT4H35M', 'id': '3', 'numberOfStops': 0, 'blacklistedInEU': False}, {'departure': {'iataCode': 'TLV', 'terminal': '1', 'at': '2023-06-09T09:05:00'}, 'arrival': {'iataCode': 'ATH', 'at': '2023-06-09T11:15:00'}, 'carrierCode': 'IZ', 'number': '211', 'aircraft': {'code': '73H'}, 'operating': {'carrierCode': 'QS'}, 'duration': 'PT2H10M', 'id': '4', 'numberOfStops': 0, 'blacklistedInEU': False}]}], 'price': {'currency': 'EUR', 'total': '147.32', 'base': '112.00', 'fees': [{'amount': '0.00', 'type': 'SUPPLIER'}, {'amount': '0.00', 'type': 'TICKETING'}], 'grandTotal': '147.32', 'additionalServices': [{'amount': '37.33', 'type': 'CHECKED_BAGS'}]}, 'pricingOptions': {'fareType': ['PUBLISHED'], 'includedCheckedBagsOnly': False}, 'validatingAirlineCodes': ['IZ'], 'travelerPricings': [{'travelerId': '1', 'fareOption': 'STANDARD', 'travelerType': 'ADULT', 'price': {'currency': 'EUR', 'total': '147.32', 'base': '112.00'}, 'fareDetailsBySegment': [{'segmentId': '3', 'cabin': 'ECONOMY', 'fareBasis': 'XSIP', 'class': 'X', 'includedCheckedBags': {'quantity': 0}}, {'segmentId': '4', 'cabin': 'ECONOMY', 'fareBasis': 'XSIP', 'class': 'X', 'includedCheckedBags': {'quantity': 0}}]}]}"`

I've tried both json.dumps() or bson.json_util.dumps() functions, with a variety of indentations, applied at a variety of different ways, as well as casting to string, list, and several other modifications and variations

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are converting the data retrieved from MongoDB into a string, and then trying to use `json.dumps()` on that string. This will not work as you expect, since `json.dumps()` expects a dictionary, list, or other JSON serializable object, not a string.

```
from bson.json_util import dumps

def loadDatabase():
    try:
        client.admin.command('ping')
        # logger.info("Successfully connected to MongoDB")
        # print("Database - You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
        # flightCollection.delete_many({}) 
        # flightCollection.insert_many(loadFlights())
        data = flightCollection.find({})
        
        # Convert cursor into list of dictionaries
        documents = [doc for doc in data]

        # Use bson.json_util.dumps to serialize the ObjectId's
        output = dumps(documents, indent=4)
        return output
```

Notice that I used dumps from `bson.json_util` instead of `json.dumps` because it is capable of serializing `ObjectId` instances that are commonly used as document IDs in MongoDB. The standard `json.dumps` function does not understand how to serialize these instances.

Read more [here](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html)